# Make the Stage transparent with Actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, transparent, presenter

I have been given a build structure that is essentially a shell swf, which I have full access to, and it loads in swf content from Articulate, Presenter, Quizmaker and Engage.

Unfortunately all of the above do not allow a transparent background option on export - so I'd either really like to be proved wrong about that, or alternatively be directed on how to make the output swfs have a transparent Stage/background.

My shell swf has access to those swfs once they're loaded... so I figure that's where I'd do whatever I need to do.

cheers,
d

Comment: Are you trying to put your swf in a HTML page? If so, set the wmode to transparent. You can't set the stage to be transparent from AS or in the Flash IDE.

Comment: Ayup, thats set, still no joy, see comment to Lars.. pretty sure thats happening :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stage is transparent by default, kind of. If you set wmode="transparent" in the HTML for the Flash Player plugin, only the content of the swf, like MovieClips and graphics, are visible, the stage is not.

Edit: same goes for the swf's you load into your shell swf, they won't have a visible stage rectangle, only the content will show.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking the proprietary formats are exporting with backgrounds in them, which is incredibly annoying. I wonder, is there possibly a way for me to target something like that and switch it off? (assuming its in a targetable movieclip..)